# jquery: How to check if a keyword exists in a div?

Tags: jquery, string

How can I check f a keyword exists in a div?

for instance, this is my html,

```
<div class="item">
<div class="title">How to check if a keyword exists</div>
<div class="author">John J, 1990</div>
</div>
```

I tried with this method below but obviously doesn't work!

```
if ($('.item .author').text('John J').length > 0)
{
    alert('found John J');

}
```

any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector, like this:

```
if ($('.item .author:contains("John J")').length > 0)
{
    alert('found John J');    
}
```

...or what you're probably ultimately after, something like this:

```
$('.item .author:contains("John J")').addClass("highlight");
```

By calling [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) you're *setting* the text, not checking for it. Using [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for searching would look like this:

```
if ($('.item .author').text().indexOf("John J") != -1)
{
    alert('found John J');    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
if ($('.item .author')[0].innerText.indexOf('John J')!=-1)
{
    alert('found John J');

}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<div class="item">
<div class="title">How to check if a keyword exists</div>
<div class="author">John J, 1990</div>
</div>
I tried with this method below and it now works!
```